# Optimize search in std::deque

Tags: c++, optimization, data-structures, std, deque

I'm doing a program that has a different kind of objects and all of them are children of a virtual class. I'm doing this looking for the advantages of polymorphism that allow me to call from a manager class a certain method of all the objects without checking the specific kind of object it is.

The point is the different kind of objects need sometimes get a list of objects of a certain type.

In that moment my manager class loop thought all the objects and check the type of the object. It creates a list and return it like this:

```
std::list<std::shared_ptr<Object>> ObjectManager::GetObjectsOfType(std::string type)
{
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<Object>> objectsOfType;

    for (int i = 0; i < m_objects.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (m_objects[i]->GetType() == type)
        {
            objectsOfType.push_back(m_objects[i]);
        }
    }

    return objectsOfType;
}
```

*m_objects* is a deque. I know iterate a data structure is *normally* expensive but I want to know if is possible to polish it a little bit because now this function takes a third of all the time used in the program.

My question is: **is there any design pattern or fuction that I'm not taking into account in order to reduce the cost of this operation in my program?**

Comment: Ditch the `string` and use a `int`. Ditch the `list` and use a `vector`.

Comment: @PasserBy I thought about the vector point. But is it worth without knowing how many objects am I going to have and not being able to reserve space for them at the beginning of my program?

Comment: A formal response is: it depends on your use case. A realistic response is: who am I kidding, always yes.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. As the list size increases random access will get much, *much* slower, and even reading one at a time is going to be awful slow compared to vector. Vector doesn't reallocate each time you push an element, it reserves some space automatically when you push to avoid reallocation too often.

Comment: @Asu: Why are you assuming random access? The code clearly shows linear access.

Comment: Also, if the caller doesn't actually need (shared) ownership of the Objects, then don't return smart pointers to Objects, but return ordinary non-owning `Object*` or `std::reference_wrapper<Object>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code as given, there is just a single optimization that can be done locally:

```
for (auto const& obj : m_objects)
{
    if (obj->GetType() == type)
    {
        objectsOfType.push_back(obj);
    }
}
```

The rationale is that `operator[]` is generally not the most efficient way to access a `deque`. Having said that, I don't expect a major improvement. Your locality of reference is very poor: You're essentially looking at two dereferences (`shared_ptr` and `string`).

A logical approach would be to make `m_objects` a `std::multimap` keyed by type.

Answer (score 1):

Some things you can do to speed up:

- Store the type on the base class, this will remove a somewhat expensive virtual lookup.
- If type is a `string`, etc. change to a
  simpel type like an enum or int
- A `vector` is more effiecient to
  traverse than a `deque`
- if staying with `deque`, use iterators or a range based for loop to avoid the random lookups (which are more expensive in `deque`)

Range based looks like this:

```
for (auto const& obj : m_objects)
{
    if (obj->GetType() == type)
    {
        objectsOfType.push_back(obj);
    }
}
```

Update: Also I would recommend against using a `std::list` (unless for some reason you have to) as it is not really performing well in many cases - again `std::vector` springs to the rescue !